# Installing a Python Module from Github in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, github, installation

I want to install the owlpy module that is currently available on GitHub --https://github.com/rob-med/owlpy-- but can not be installed using pip.

In the GitHub page I am advised as follows:

> Clone this repo and run:
>
> ```
> python setup.py install
> ```

I am not sure though what I should do once I download the zip file.  Where should I place its contents so that command runs successfully.

Moreover I will run the command as exactly appears in my Command Window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need run this command with administrator privileges.

Download and extract the zip and open command prompt with RunAsAdmin mode and run the same command.

```
python setup.py install
```

If the problem still persists, post the error trace to analyse.

If you don’t have admin privileges try installing it in python virtualenv
https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Comment: Thank you.  Two clarifications please: It does not matter in which folder I will extract the zip file?  Do I need to make any changes to the system variables?

Comment: No it doesn't matter where you extract the zip, because during installation all the required files will be copied to the python installation directory or virtualenv directory if you use virtualenv. It is just like installing any exe in your system. No need to change the system variables.